# how to extract 10 digit number from column excel

Tags: excel

I have column which consists of text including 13 digit number. How Can I keep 10 digit number and delete all other text?
Please help me I am new to excel..
thanks in advance

Edited:
Cell Format

```
[6/11/2013 3:26:37 PM]         1234503776599, ksdfl 038ddf63Ksdf)
[6/12/2013 3:26:37 PM]         0234503664599, ksdfadssdfl 038ddf6dfsd3Ksdf)
[6/13/2013 3:26:37 PM]         7234503666099, 45sdsdfadssdfl 03845ddf6dfsd3Ksdf)
```

Here, In second column I want to keep 13 digit and delete all text after that 13 digit.

Comment: How is the text in the cell formatted? Can you post several examples

Comment: `1234813717967,sdfsd dsfsdsdf), this is some text number is 10545, RESULT`  -> here I want to extract 13 digit 1234813717967 from all rows

Comment: that whole comma'ed string is in one cell?

Comment: I have thousands of rows and this is one example of particular cell in which all cell consists of 13 digits as in this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the number always at the beginning of the cell? If so you can use `=LEFT(cell_ref, 10)` to extract the first 10 characters, which in this case are numbers and will be treated as such by the spreadsheet.

Comment: Here's a [reference](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=113:excel-text-and-string-functions-left-right-mid-len-find-search-replace-substitute&catid=78:excel-functions-formulas&Itemid=474)

Comment: I have never use excel. would you please explain where should I place this formula step by step. thanks

Comment: @CodeManiac in the formula box

Comment: If your data is in column 'x' then put the formula in column 'y'.Nathan's answer below will work for what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you will need something like this

```
=MID(A1,32,FIND(",",A1,32) -32)
```

MID will get text from the middle of a string
FIND will get the location of the first comma

Answer (score 0):

Thinking that the 13 digit number is in the middle of the string, with 9 spaces to the left and a comma to the right we can use the following formula in a separate cell:

```
=MID(A1,LEN(LEFT(A1,FIND("]",A1)+1))+9,13)
```

The `LEN` function determines the length of the part up to and including `]` (big bracket). Then the number 9 is added to include nine spaces. Then the number 13 is the length of the 13 digit number. All these are used as parameters for the `MID`  function.

After you get the result just drag down using the autofill handle to get the mid 13 digit number for all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

`=LOOKUP(10^11,MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-9)),11)+0)`

This works for me.

Answer (score -1):

To extract 6 continuous numeric digits, use the below code:

```
=LOOKUP(10^6,MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-5)),6)+0)
```

Replace 6 in the above code with the number of digits that are required to be extracted.

Comment: The asker needs 10 digits, not 6, could you provide an answer for that?