# This Excel function extracts an N-digit number from a string. How does it work?

Tags: excel, extract

I've attempted to write an Excel function that extracts any N-digit number from a long alphanumeric string. I found a example online in a couple of places ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30108502/7432297), [2](http://chandoo.org/wp/2016/05/06/extract-the-10-digit-number-formula-homework/#comment-1181289)) that works, but I can't figure out how.

For example, given the string `0xabc_2014528888_abcde_30285_q!`, the function should return `2014528888` (assuming N = 10).

I found the following Excel snippet in a couple of places (here for N=10):

```
=LOOKUP(10^10,MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-9)),10)+0)
```

But I can't understand how it works.

1. Microsoft's [LOOKUP() function documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb) says that the first argument to `LOOKUP()` is the lookup value... how does setting that value to 10^N return N characters?
2. The `INDIRECT()` function seems like it's getting the argument `1:21` (in my example string). How is this a valid cell reference? If I enter it in a cell by itself, it doesn't compute anything sensible.

Can anybody explain what this function is doing to extract a numeric sequence?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give this a shot, though there are some parts I'm not sure about.

Basically, what we have here is an array formula that's not being entered as an array - that is, when given a range of values, it will perform its function for each possible value, rather than for the whole range at once.

`INDIRECT("$1:$22")` returns a reference to all of rows `1` through `22`. The `ROW` function then uses that reference to those rows to return a list or array (this is the part I'm not sure about - I'm not sure how it's creating an array) of numbers `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;...22}`

It then uses `MID` to return all strings of 10 characters from the source value, using the array of linear numbers from before as the starting points. `MID` returns another array, `{"0xabc 2014";"xabc 20145";"abc 201452";..."e 30285 q!"}`. The strings are then forced to perform a mathematical function by the +1. This forces any strings in the array that contain non-numeric characters to return `#VALUE!` errors, while numeric strings return themselves as a value. We get an array like `{#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;2014528888;#VALUE!;...}`

Finally, `LOOKUP` looks through that array and finds the largest value that is smaller than the first argument - that is, the only result in the array that does not return #VALUE!

I suspect - but cannot state for sure - that the key is using `LOOKUP` instead of `VLOOKUP` or any other database function. `LOOKUP` has two modes of operation - a Vector mode, and an Array mode. I suspect that if used in Array mode, it will force any data fed into its second argument to become an array.